# Distribution of min/max row sum of matrix with i.i.d. uniform random variables

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, matrices, random-matrices

Given a $n\times n$ symmetric random matrix such that

> 1. all **diagonal** elements are all **fixed** as $1$.
> 2. all elements in upper triangle (excluding the diagonal) are **i.i.d. uniform** random variables over $[0,1]$. Lower triangle values are set accordingly to ensure symmetry.

The questions is:

> Is there any known result for the distribution of the min/max row sum; or any suggested method to find this?

I make an experiment over a $100\times 100$ such random matrix, and the histogram of the **min row sum divided by 100** (which normalizes the value to $[0,1]$) looks like the following

> [image]

and the maximum row sum divided by 100,

> [image]

Comment: This is very similar to finding the distribution of the maximum degree of a random graph and for sure the same method will give the asymptotic distribution of the $k$-th largest row sum for any fixed $k$.  One reference is the book Random Graphs by Béla Bollobás.  If I recall correctly, set a threshold at the right place (something like $n/2+cn^{1/2}\log n/\log\log n$) and find that the number of row sums exceeding the threshold is asymptotically Poisson.

Comment: For large $n$, the sum of each row is close to a normal distribution with mean $n/2$ and variance $n/12$. That is: about $n/2+\sqrt{n/12}N$, where the $N$ are independent standard normal random variables. To find the typical maximum of $n$ standard normals, solve the equation $\mathbb P(N>t)=1/n$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas The rows are not independent due to the symmetry of the matrix. Thus, your $N$s are not independent.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, i could say that the row sums have an approximate multi-variate normal distribution with means $n/6$ and covariant matrix with $n/12$ on the diagonal and $1/6$ off the diagonal. A family of multi-variate normals with the same distribution is $n/2+\sqrt{1/6}N_0+\sqrt{(n-2)/12}N_i}$, where $N_0,...,N_n$ are independent standard normals. Now you can use the previous argument.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas not quite; convergence to Gaussian is in the sense of multivariate distribution when the number of rows is fixed and the dimension grows. You can't take a number of variables that grows with the dimension. In any case, Brendan McKay is right that the answer should be similar to  Bollobas' inhttps://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X80900540 which would be indeed n/2+c\sqrt{n\log n}. That this is an upper bound follows from a union bound, and the lower bound could be proved by a second moment argument.